# Concurrent TCP server in C++

Tags: c++, tcp, concurrency, server

I am trying to create a concurrent c++ TCP server using threads. In particular I was wondering if I could use std::async to accept connections and serve each one in its own thread.

So far I have created a rough mockup but can't really tell if I am on the correct path.

```
void networking::TCP_Server::acceptConnection() {
    std::string stringToSend{"This is a test string to be replied to"};
    int new_fd = accept(listeningFD, nullptr, nullptr);
    send(new_fd, stringToSend.c_str(), stringToSend.size(), 0);
    sleep(3);
    std::cout << ("End of thread");

}
```

```
///LISTEN FOR CONNECTIONS ON listeningFD
///CREATE A LIST OF FILE DESCRIPTORS FOR POLL fds[]


(fds[i].fd == listeningFD)  {

 do {
                        std::cout << ("New incoming connection - %d\n", new_fd);
                        std::async(std::launch::async, acceptConnection)

                    } while (new_fd != -1);


                }  /* End of existing connection is readable             */
            } /* End of loop through pollable descriptors              */
```

I am connecting at the same time to the server with two clients and would expect for the loop to run through both new connections and create a thread for each one. As of now it is as it runs in deferred mode, one gets accepted, the other waits until the first finishes.

Any ideas?

(Pardon any mistakes in the code)

Answer (score 1):

`std::async` returns a `std::future` which the code doesn't save into a variable, hence its destructor is called immediately. [`std::future::~future()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/~future) blocks the calling thread until the future becomes ready.

You may like to use (detached) `std::thread` instead of `std::async`.

There are more scalable strategies to handle many clients. I highly recommend reading old but instructive [The C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html).

You may also like to get familar with [Asio C++ Library](https://think-async.com/Asio/).